# Why does the datetimepicker give month name instead of number?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, datetimepicker

I'm trying to use DateTimePicker in my application.
I create Date.cshtml under the View/Shared/EditorTemplates folder
and it consist something like this:

```
@model System.DateTime

@Html.TextBox("", Model.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy"),
new {@class = "tanggal", @maxlength = "10"})
```

then I create EditorHookup.js file under the script folder with the content like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.tanggal').datepicker({
        dateFormat: 'dd-MM-yyyy'
    });
});
```

I expect to get the result to be like this: 01-01-2012
but the result is: 01-January-20122012

What should I do to fix that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `mm` for month instead of `MM`. See here: http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Datepicker/formatDate

E.g.:

```
dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy'     //notice the year format also has been changed, per Izkata's comment
```

Comment: Also, use 'yy' instead of 'yyyy'

Comment: If I change MM to mm in Date.cshtml, the month will be 00

Comment: @Tanu, sorry, the change needs to be made in the jQuery call: `dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy'`.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the help. I have made a changes in my .js file to 'dd-mm-yy', the month result is changed, but the year still double (01-01-20122012)

Comment: @Tanu, be sure the year is `yy`, *not* `yyyy`. See the documenation referenced.

Comment: @JonathanM: Aah it seems the browser keep the catche, after close it and start it again, it run as expected. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1):

Double-check the documentation for your datepicker, specifically regarding the code for month.  I'd guess that you want something like `mm` instead of `MM`.

Answer (score 1):

can you try

```
dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy'
```

http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/#option-dateFormat

Comment: the month result format is change to the expected, but the year still double (01-01-20122012)

Comment: Thank you very much. The datetimepicker is run as expected now